# Why is my function returning unicode replacement characters

Tags: javascript, express, cryptojs

I'm trying to add encryption for passwords, and want to store the hashes and have the encryption/decryption being done on signup/login, the encryption goes fine from utf8 to hex, but when I try to decrypt, I get back a bunch of weird letters that look like:

> "\ufffd'\rF\ufffd\ufffd\¡\ufffd6>\ufffd\ufffd#B,0\u0005\u0007\ufffd?\ufffd;\ufffd\u0018\u001e\"oؕ"

I've been trying to figure out how it could be using the wrong encoding data, as I have the hex and utf8 tags in the right places; I've been trying to look at other posts too, but I'm afraid they go over my head over how they're supposed to help me.

### This is in the first file that I export it from

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

    var secretkey = "twinkies";
    var key = {
    encrypt: function(pass){
        var mykey = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', secretkey);
        var finpass = mykey.update(pass, 'utf8', 'hex');
        finpass += mykey.final('hex');
        return finpass;
    },

    decrypt: function(pass){
        var mykey = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', secretkey);
        var finpass = mykey.update(pass, 'hex', 'utf8');
        finpass += mykey.final('utf8');
        return finpass;
    }
};
```

### this is the second file that uses the methods

```
    app.post("/api/users/create", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.pword);
    var newpass = key.encrypt(req.body.pword);
    var oldpass = key.decrypt(newpass);
    var enddata = {
        Ciphored_password : newpass,
        Deciphored_password : oldpass
    }
    console.log(res.json(enddata));
```

I use postman to test my localhost api, and am putting in 'bigthonks' as the password, when it console logs the enddata the Ciphored_password looks like:

> 982cb6d27f65fbb642c8c7b710e6c349

and the Deciphored_password:

> "\ufffd'\rF\ufffd\ufffd\¡\ufffd6>\ufffd\ufffd#B,0\u0005\u0007\ufffd?\ufffd;\ufffd\u0018\u001e\"oؕ"

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I'm an idiot... I missed one of the first steps of bugfixing which is looking at methodnames,

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var secretkey = "twinkies";
var key = {
encrypt: function(pass){
    var mykey = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', secretkey);
    var finpass = mykey.update(pass, 'utf8', 'hex');
    finpass += mykey.final('hex');
    return finpass;
},

decrypt: function(pass){
    var mykey = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', secretkey);
    var finpass = mykey.update(pass, 'hex', 'utf8');
    finpass += mykey.final('utf8');
    return finpass;
}
};
```

on my decrypt method, when I'm generating the decipher for it i use the createCipher() method instead of the createDecipher() method, really big woops on my part.

I easily fixed it by changing the decrypt method to this:

```
    decrypt: function(pass){
    var mykey = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-cbc', secretkey);
    var finpass = mykey.update(pass, 'hex', 'utf8');
    finpass += mykey.final('utf8');
    return finpass;
}
```

and now it works.